# using text.get to obtain a string and characters - python

Tags: python-3.x, text, tkinter, widget

I'm using the `text.get` command in a text widget to obtain the first group of numbers from a list, but as my numbers(s) contains characters (specifically a dash -) I don't get the complete string. Also, my list while all have a dashes in them are differing lengths so its not as simple as stating a start point + x number of characters.

i.e

```
123-678

1234-456

145-12341
```

What I would like to obtain is the entire string that includes the first set of numbers, the dash, then the next set of numbers and ignore any spaces afterwards

I've been using the :

```
getnumber=text.get("start and end")
```

and have been able to get an entire line of text to print, the entire text widget, and in the case of the first example above only "123". There appears to be plenty of examples but I cannot find one that applies to what I'm after hence my question

The code I'm using is

```
self.outputbox.tag_configure("dwg", foreground="white", background="red")  
self.outputbox.tag_remove("dwg", "1.0", "end")
self.outputbox.tag_add("dwg", "insert linestart", "insert lineend")
getdwg=self.outputbox.get("insert linestart", "insert wordend")
   print(getdwg)
```

However when I click the area of the text box and the output prints it will only print a small part of the information, though I have noticed if for example 1234-34578 is clicked in the '1234' area that prints only, if I click on the dash then 1234- prints, if I click on the 34578 area then 1234-34578 prints (as required). However I wish this output to occur regardless of the area of the string that is click

Comment: What's your question? You haven't asked anything.

Comment: @BryanOakley appologies, I thought my initial post was sufficient, but have clarified.

Comment: your edit didn't help at all. You need to show us some code, and what problem you're having with the code. What have you tried? What was the result? How is it different than what you expect?

Comment: @BryanOakley, updated as above. I realise to a seasoned programmer this is probably very trivial, but to people learning the information isnt always easily found or understandable :)

Comment: The problem isn't that it's trivial, the problem is that the question is unclear. You haven't asked anything. You simply say "I want x" without showing any code or any research. There's simply no way to know what you're struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code is invalid:

```
getnumber=text.get("start and end")
```

The string `"start and end"` is not a valid index. If you want to get a single line you must give a valid index for the start of the line, and then you can give the same index with `"lineend"` appended for the second index. For example, to get line 1 you could do:

```
getnumber = text.get("1.0", "1.0 lineend")
```

If there are potentially extra spaces at the start and end of the line, you can strip them off as a second step:

```
getnumber = getnumber.strip()
```

Comment: I realise the "start and end" syntax is incorrect, I put it in there (realising now its most likely awfully confusing) to show what I was attempting to do. I'm currently playing around with using     text.get("insert linestart", "insert wordend")     but not getting the desired effect (i.e. only the numbers before the dash print). Indexes didnt appear to work for me either, im assuming because the items I'm clicking are on different lines of the text widget.

Comment: @LMP2016: we'll never know if you choose to not share your code with us. Rest assured, tkinter text widget indexes work as documented, and are extremely reliable.

Comment: @LMP2016: please don't post code  in a comment. Edit you wuestion and put it there.

Comment: Have added the reply to the bottom of your reply (pending a peer review) I will copy it up to my original post

Answer (score 0):

May be you used the wrong method or you used wrong indexes. Here is a simple code that shows how to get what you want:

```
import Tkinter as Tk    

root = Tk.Tk()
text = Tk.Text(root)
text.insert(Tk.INSERT, "123-678\n")
text.insert(Tk.END, "1234-456\n")
text.insert(Tk.END, "145-12341")
text.pack()    
print text.get('1.0', '1.7') # First line
print text.get('2.0', '2.8') # Second line
print text.get('3.0', '3.9') # Third line

root.mainloop()
```

**Demo:**

If you run the program above, you will get this:

[image]

And the lines are correctly printed on Terminal:

[image]

Comment: as my text widget displays text on multiple lines (the number of lines can vary) I dont think using indexes will work for me. My code as it stands is<br/>    getdwg=self.dwgoutputbox.get("insert linestart", "insert wordend")
    print(getdwg) and this yields<br/>699 where it should be 699-123  1851 where it should be 1851-345<br/>1849 where it should be 1849-267<br/>there are more lines in my text widget but this is just an example<br/> I have however noticed if I click my mouse on 699-123 but the "123" part of the number it prints correct

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it would have been nice to have the program select the text for each line, stopping when it hit empty space, but that was beyond my expertise. Instead I worked out a worse case and implemented `linestart+10c` and because my text widget has tabs between the printed data it works nicely.
The code as written is

```
        self.DwgOutputBox.tag_remove("dwg", "1.0", "end")
        self.DwgOutputBox.tag_configure("dwg", background="red")
        self.DwgOutputBox.tag_add("dwg", "insert linestart", "insert lineend")
        getdwg=self.DwgOutputBox.get("insert linestart", "insert linestart+10c")
        getdwg=getdwg.strip()
```